# How to use nbind wrapping C++ gRPC interface generated by FlatBuffers compiler as a Javascript/Typescript interface?

Tags: javascript, c++, typescript, grpc, flatbuffers

Currently (July 2019) Flatbuffers doesn't have (yet) gRPC generators for Javascript and Typescript. How nbind could be used to generated such Javascript/Typescript interface? An nbind example based on one of Flatbuffers' examples would be great.

Answer (score 1):

If/when JS/TS are supported for FlatBuffers + gRPC, we'd likely want to have a native implementation rather than relying on converting all of C++ gRPC (which is rather large). Something that relies on https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web

FlatBuffers requires specific code to be generated for the API defined in the schema, where we'd want to share code with however gRPC currently generates code for Protobuf.. and the JS runtime code currently used by gRPC + Protobuf. This would look very different from using nbind / would not use nbind.

Also, nbind seems to rely on asm.js, whereas nowadays one would want to use WebAssembly to run C++ on the web :)

Comment: Thanks for info. I think the JS/TS gRPC support in Flatbuffers is an important expected feature. The interest implementing this feature should be high. What are the difficulties implementing it?

Comment: @Flaviu I don't think there are any difficulties, it's just some work, and somebody has to do it :)